# Why do I keep receiving a "fatal: Authentication failled..." message when trying to perform a git push on my new page?

Tags: html, github, terminal

I'm taking a beginner developer course and the instructor has us setting up a page in github, but the instructions are outdated by a few years and the FAQ isn't helping. I've set up my repository and page (though it's not giving me a theme like the instructor is showing) but when I go to my terminal and make changes, everything works fine until I get to git push. Then it gives me the message:

remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/michael-network/michael-network.github.io.git/'

Any ideas what the issue is?

1. I tried setting up a public key but wasn't able to complete the process because I kept receiving the message "Key is invalid. You must supply a key in OpenSSH public key format" when inputing key.
2. I tried "git remote -v" as recommended in a thread but got the message "fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists." on my terminal.

Comment: So how did you generate your key? https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent seems fairly easy to follow.